# How to format the output string in python?

Tags: python

I want to print output like this:

```
stock name : TATASTEEL           ltp : 1084.70   
stock name : NMDC                ltp : 182.60
stock name : HDFC                ltp : 2583.10
stock name : INDIGO              ltp : 1745.70
stock name : ZEEL                ltp : 213.50
stock name : ICICIBANK           ltp : 653.90
```

I am currently trying to do this with following code:

```
print('stock name : {0} \t  ltp : {1}'.format(stock_name, ltp))
```

What i actually get, is this:

```
stock name : INDIGO              ltp : 1745.70    
stock name : ZEEL                ltp : 213.50
stock name : ICICIBANK           ltp : 653.90
stock name : NAVINFLUOR                  ltp : 3191.00
```

How can I achieve that the output is properly aligned? Adding another `\t` did not solve the problem.

Comment: Do you know the maximum length of stock names?

Comment: No, but as mentioned in answer below i can vary it as per need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the width for a variable to print with:

```
print('stock name : {0: <20} ltp : {1}'.format(stock_name, ltp))
```

The alterative (and in my optionion nicer looking) solution, would be f-strings:

```
print(f'stock name : {stock_name: <20} ltp : {ltp}')
```

In both cases, the width for where `stock_name` is placed into the string is `20`, with `stock_name` being left-aligned (Pay attention to the `<`).

Comment: this worked, can you tell me why even after adding two or three tabs , output was not alligned?

Comment: Because the name of the stocks have differnt lengths. `\t` creates spaces until the next tab stop. If a stock name, e.g. NAVINFLUOR is too long and exceed the tab stop of previous names, it will create spaces to the next tab stop. This leads to a shift in the alignment. My solution is different, as it creates a fixed size space for the name.

Comment: i am new to this platform, this question is tagged as duplicate, should i delete it?

Comment: That's not necessary, but you should accept @AnsFourtyTwo's answer (click the checkmark) :)

Comment: I have one more question, If there are two print statements can I print them on two different terminals?

Comment: I think I should use tkinter